# build package with overloaded operator

Tags: r, devtools

I'm new to building packages with R and I am starting with making a package that combines some functions that I wrote and often load independently. Among those functions there is an overloaded + operator for concatenating strings. It's simply:

```
`+` = function(x,y) {
    if(is.character(x) | is.character(y)) {
        return(paste(x , y, sep=""))
    } else {
        .Primitive("+")(x,y)
    }
}
```

I build the package in Rstudio and the package compiles and I can load it fine. But the + operator is missing from package when I load it. What am I missing?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] TBKUseful_0.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.2     withr_1.0.2     memoise_1.0.0   digest_0.6.12   devtools_1.12.0
```

Comment: What is the content of your NAMESPACE file? (Overloading `+` is a bad idea, at least from a performance perspective.)

Comment: Did you export that function?

Comment: hi, 
@Roland my NAMESPACE file has just: exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")

Comment: @Axeman I am not familiar with what you mean - sorry still a newbie.

Comment: I'd advise going through [Hadley's little package book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/). You need to export functions for them to be available to package users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP has said that they export functions using `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")`, i.e., specify functions to export using a regex. Well, that regex does not match `"+"`:

```
grepl("^[[:alpha:]]+", "+")
#[1] FALSE
```

*Writing R Extensions* [recommends](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports) the following to export everything not starting with a dot:

```
exportPattern("^[^\\.]")
```

Testing the regex:

```
grepl("^[^\\.]", "+")
#[1] TRUE
```

Note that using `export` for exporting specific functions is better practice.

Comment: This works. Thank you. I will have to go through "Writing R Extensions" at some point

Comment: If you intend to create packages (you should) you'll need to consult it frequently. It's the the official documentation. Don't bother too much with other tutorials. They are often outdated.